# Why is my Add Button Returning a Null Reference Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several buttons in my web app that I want to use to add/remove from one box to another.  Using the following code which has worked in the past I am receiving a null reference error

The error points to the -1; in the line  for (int i = lbAppsI.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
below

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = lbAppsI.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (lbAppsI.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                lbImpactedApps.Items.Add(new ListItem(lbAppsI.Items[i].Text, lbAppsI.Items     
 [i].Value + ","));
            }
      }
    }
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object is the error thrown.

entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;

namespace LandscapeServices
{
public partial class Update : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string query { get; set; }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LandscapeServicesConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    string[] IApps;
    string[] SApps;
    ListBox lbImpactedApps;
    ListBox lbSupportingApps;
    ListBox lbAppsI;
    ListBox lbAppsS;
    TextBox txtPrj;
    TextBox txtArt;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

    }


    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        string ImpactedApp = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView)(sender)).Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("Label10"))).Text;
        IApps = ImpactedApp.Split(',');

        string SupportingApp = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView)(sender)).Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("Label11"))).Text;
        SApps = SupportingApp.Split(',');
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                lbImpactedApps = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("ListBox1");
                lbSupportingApps = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("ListBox2");
                lbAppsI = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("ListBox3");
                lbAppsS = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("ListBox4");
                txtPrj = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtProjectName");

                foreach (string lst in IApps)
                {
                    lbImpactedApps.Items.Add(lst.ToString());
                    //lbImpactedApps.Items.FindByText(lst.ToString()).Selected = true;

                }

                lbImpactedApps.DataBind();

                foreach (string lst in SApps)
                {
                    lbSupportingApps.Items.Add(lst.ToString());
                    //lbSupportingApps.Items.FindByText(lst.ToString()).Selected = true;

                }

                lbSupportingApps.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = lbAppsI.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (lbAppsI.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                lbImpactedApps.Items.Add(new ListItem(lbAppsI.Items[i].Text, lbAppsI.Items[i].Value + ","));
            }
      }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Comment: what have you tried to fix this yourself? attached with a debugger? read the "What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?" question? anything ...?

Comment: lbAppsI is probably not initialized at this point.  It should be declared (otherwise you'd get a syntax error at compile-time), but make sure you've initialized it.  Otherwise, `Items` will be null, and trying to get the `Count` of a null object will cause problems

Comment: To hunt this create variables for each step. One for `lbAppsI`, another for `lbAppsI.Items` and other for `lbAppsI.Items.Count`. Just see in what line it will break. Probably in the fist as @RussellUhl pointed. I think even if there are no items in `lbAppsI` its `Items` will be instantiated.

Comment: I think these answers are great.  If someone could specifically explain how to do this I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear  : the `lbAppsI` is decalred but not initialized .So the exception is thrown when you try to read the `items` property of `lbAppsI` object which is null

Verify this by debugging your code , put a breakpoint here

```
for (int i = lbAppsI.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Normally you will get `lbAppsI=null`

Comment: Thats a decent answer and you are correct.  I am having an issue initializing the object.  Is there a formalized/preferred way to do this?

Comment: @OnceorTwice post all the class implementation to tell u where and how you can do  it

Comment: I have added it to my original post.

Comment: @OnceorTwice First at all: avoid to open connection in the load of the page because in every post back to the page you try to open it!!! just use con.Open() when you need. Besides, I don't understand why you do this `ListBox lbAppsI;` if I understood this listbox exists in design part so you need just know its name and use it in the code behind without redefinig it , in your case the `lbAppsI` is not in the view part as you think , it is a new one. just do this `this.` and the intellisense feature helps you and list all the controls' names in the view page

Comment: I think part of your answer got cut off. You said just do " this" and then nothing was posted there.

Comment: @OnceorTwice the last part of the comment : it is a new one. just do `this.` and the intellisense feature helps you and list all the controls' names in the view page